# Singular value decomposition in R - limited number of singular values from svd()

Tags: r, svd

In R's documentation for the `svd()` function, there is an example at the bottom.

```
hilbert <- function(n) { i <- 1:n; 1 / outer(i - 1, i, "+") }
X <- hilbert(9)[, 1:6]
```

Instead of the default input values, I wanted to set

- nu = number of rows
- nv = number of columns

so I ran

```
s = svd(X, nu = dim(X)[1], nv = dim(X)[2])
```

Here are the dimensions of matrices in "s".

```
> str(s)
List of 3
 $ d: num [1:6] 1.67 2.77e-01 2.22e-02 1.08e-03 3.24e-05 ...
 $ u: num [1:9, 1:9] -0.724 -0.428 -0.312 -0.248 -0.206 ...
 $ v: num [1:6, 1:6] -0.736 -0.443 -0.327 -0.263 -0.22 ...
```

I expected `d` to have a length of 9, but it has a length of 6 instead.  Why?

Comment: Because `svd` only returns the nonzero singular values. If your matrix is n-by-m at most it can have min(n,m) nonzero singular values.

Comment: Thanks, Ernest A, for your clear answer!  You should put your comment as an answer and get the credit that you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two versions of SVD. The simple SVD of a matrix consists of finding some matrices *U*, *D*, *V* such that *X* = *UDV*', where *D* is diagonal and *U*, *V* are orthogonal.  The columns of *U* are an orthogonal basis of the column space of *X*, whereas the columns of *V* are an orthogonal basis of the row space of *X*. If *X* is *n* × *m* with rank *r*, from linear algebra we know that *r* is the number of linearly independent columns which is the same as the number of linearly independent rows.  Therefore *U*  must be *n* x *r* and *V* *m* x *r*. It follows that *D* is diagonal *r* x *r*.

In the other version of SVD, *U* and *V* are completed with an orthogonal basis of the left null space and the null space of *X* respectively. In this case, *U* and *V* are square matrices, *n* x *n* and *m* x *m*, and *D* is *n* x *m* thus no longer diagonal.  The extra entries in the non-diagonal *D* matrix are zeroes.  Because the extra singular values are of little interest (since they're all zero) these are not returned by the function `svd`.